# Acumatica [Unauthorized Request]

Tags: c#, acumatica, unauthorized

I'm having random error on my customized screen.
It seems fine on few minutes, and then this pop-up shows.

It says `"Unauthorized Request"`, I checked on the Trace Screen, It doesn't point where the error raises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Acumatica. I would check with Acumatica as they provided a patch for us in the past. Not sure what version this might be fixed in. Some developers were able to get the errors, and others were not. The patch was a few updated dll and update to the web.config.

I cannot remember the exact details, but if it helps temporarily try to use a different browser or clear browser cache. I think that helped some people.

If not on the latest build for the version you are on, you can also try this. I think it was resolved near the end of June but not exactly sure.

Answer (score 0):

It worked! I updated the next step build, and `Clear Cache` saves my life